# Are there known issues for using PHP POST data with mobile devices?

Tags: php, android, ios, forms, http-post

I have a PHP form that self processes. It passes data with POST. Works flawlessly on desktop browsers but does not work on Chrome for Android, Safari or Chrome for iOS and iOS simulator. For the sake of brevity, I will share the parts of this file that are not working as there is quite a bit of validation that goes on.

Here is the beginning of my HTML form input:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<div class="voucher-input first-input">
Voucher 1: <input maxlength="20" type="text" name="voucher1" id="voucher1" title="Voucher" class="input" value="<?php echo $voucher1;?>">
```

Here is the receiving part of my form "action" that captures POST data:

```
$voucher1 = test_input($_POST["voucher1"]);
```

When it captures this voucher1, it passes it off for form validation. The first step is to remove white space and illegal characters, then it ensures that the voucher is prefixed with a valid 3 letter prefix (in this case I am using STL). If that passes, then it goes through the trouble of adding it to a PHP array.

```
$stl = 'STL'; // Defines a string that is needed for the next step

$posstl = strpos($voucher1, $stl); // Checks if 'STL' is at beginning of $voucher1 input. All vouchers must start with an authorized prefix.

    if ($posstl === 0) { // If STL is at the beginning of position 0 of string


    /** Create Empty Voucher Array **/
    $redeemids = array();

    echo "Adding voucher to array";
    array_push($redeemids, $voucher1);
    print_r($redeemids);}
```

On desktops, it does all of this. On mobile, it doesn't even echo "Adding voucher to array" which tells me it is failing the IF conditional for mobile devices. So to eliminate the variables, either this method of POST does not work for mobile, my form HTML is invalid or the there is a problem with my conditional. Any ideas?

Comment: You could do `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script and then check your server error logs to see if that helps.

Comment: You should echo $voucher1 to begin with. As following if conditions depend on the value.

Comment: What is the used char encoding of the page?

Comment: what does this show echo($_POST["voucher1"]); ? put it 1st line in action php file

Comment: Character encoding is being declared at top of document as "<meta charset="UTF-8">". Running the suggested tests now.

Comment: As it is the php code that should prefix a 'STL' you know who to blame when it fails.

Comment: Alright, I have turned on error reporting and echoed out variables. No errors reported and variables are indeed getting passed however I did on a whim decide to change the equal operator from === to == and now it works. I can modify my code to effectively allow me to use this conditional. This isn't an answer to my question as I still don't understand why it works one way on desktop and another on mobile...

Comment: just cruiser what echo("::".$posstl."::"); shows? on both pc and mobile, this could help to find out what going on

Comment: It echoes out 0 Yazan which is the position it should be. Based on my equal operator change, this is implying that mobile passes a different data type than desktop.

Comment: well i have a bad news then, as strpos() may retunrn FALSE or other values Evaluates to FALSE when needle not found in string, in this case 0, and 0 here means false and not pos 0, so it should be compared with === as == will be translated to FALSE==0 which could be true, so thats not what you want, check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: I see. Well is there a better way in this instance than strpos() to determine if a string begins with a certain prefix?

Comment: i am not sure, as strpos() should do the trick, but the main issue is the mobile/desktop strange behavior which i am not sure why it happens, try this echo(":".$_POST["voucher1"],":<br/>"); before the test_input() and next line of test_input() put this echo ":".$voucher1.":"; the only thing i doubt is some combination of input and something wrong occurs at test_input()

Comment: I'm going to switch to using SUBSTR() which can return the first 3 characters of my voucher. I'll then convert it to a variable and compare it to my predefined voucher prefix. I'm sure I could have continued using strpos but this is more applicable to my final goals. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: use the ":" as marker to see if there is a space at the begin of the values ...